# If variable equals something, make a have a href attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

Using advanced custom fields plugin on my wordpress site. I have a select option in one of the custom post types which determines if post going to be a link to another page or call out popup.

Here is how it looks.

```
<!-- here goes a code defining post type. Works fine -->
<?php $hmltype = get_field('post_url_or_popup'); ?>
<div class="tablecell midlineunit middle">
        <a class="table midunithref mw1" <?php if ($hmltype == hml_url) { echo 'href="<?php the_field('hplb_url'); ?>" ' } endif; ?> >
</a>
</div>
```

Must be a syntax error, but I'm just starting out with php, so, kind of difficult to find the mistake.

Comment: is`hml_url` a string? a variable?

Comment: I guess it's a string. Its value is determined by custom field. The select has 2 values: "hml_url" and "hml_popup". I've tried using it in quotes, but no luck. I just get a blank page instead of previously working one.

Comment: `hml_url` that is presently treated as a constant. If you "guess" it's a string, then that isn't good enough. We need to know exactly. Plus, `endif;` is only used when using a different conditional syntax.

Comment: then you  have this `echo 'href="<?php` a `<?php` tag set inside a PHP tag already.

Comment: There will be another similar conditional statement before that. It's a string.

Comment: So we have a *"I guess"* and a *"Let's say"*. Totally unclear. I can't do anything here.

Comment: It's a duck, but it doesn't look like a duck, so it's not a duck.

Answer (score 1):

What is `hml_url`? Is it a variable called `$hml_url`..? Back to your issues, you're using `endif;` here completely wrong. You can only ever call it if you instantiate it like this:

```
if(condition) :
    do stuff;
endif;
```

Now to fix your print.

```
<a class="table midunithref mw1" <?php echo ($hmltype == hml_url) ? 'href="'. the_field('hplb_url'); .'"' : ''; ?> >
```

You'll need to figure out/tell us what `hml_url` is for us to solve your issue. You would've also seen the error if you turned your error reporting on. You can do this by adding this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1); // or you could do E_ALL
```

Comment: [It *could* be a duck...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835827/if-variable-equals-something-make-a-have-a-href-attribute#comment49716374_30835827) but they say it's a string.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What is said ducks name? :D

Comment: Custom post type has a select field named "post_url_or_popup" with 2 values: "hml_url" and "hml_popup". And i need certain action (adding a href in this case) depending on which one is selected.

Comment: @ViciA that's great, so can you show us how you get it and assign it....

Comment: That's a first line of the code, after comment. p.s. sorry if some of what i say doesn't make since sometimes. Really new to it.

Comment: @ViciA add that code to your question, we can't guess what it looks like! Let us help you by helping us

Comment: I believe it's this piece of code you are asking about. It's included in question <?php $hmltype = get_field('post_url_or_popup'); ?>

Comment: And what does `print_r($hmltype);` give you?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the `hml_url` as a string? ->  `if($hmltype == 'hml_url')`

Comment: print_r($hmltype); gives nothing actually. I have tried quoting it